# Change gridview row color based on DateTime.Compare

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview

I am trying to change the color of my gridview row if its past the current date. I have looked around and conjured up something that seems like it should work. However it doesn't. Why?

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 114:    {
>   Line 115:
>   Line 116:        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["ExpiryDate"]); 
>   Line 117:        string Test = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,dt).ToString();
>   Line 118:

Here is my code

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["ExpiryDate"]); 
    string Test = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,dt).ToString();

    if (Test == "0")
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: is "ExpiryDate" column present in datasource that is bound to grid? also verify your row role in grid (headerrow, footerrow etc) if row does not have valid data bound to it, it will fail to give data object

Comment: I would add `rowtype` check at the beginning of event handler - `if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)`

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into it with me.

I have just verified that the column doesnt have null in the Expiry date column, also i have verified it works, when I look at my gridview without the code, its filled out properly with the date from the server

Answer (score 1):

You could check some objects and use some safe casts to check if everything is fine before using it.

The conversion could be done with a date time format, for sample `dd/MM/yyyy` or `mm/DD/yyyy` and try to extract the date with [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx). I am not sure about your date time format, but, you could try something like this (look the comments):

```
private CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if it is a row that contains data
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // convert the dataItem to your datasource type with a safe cast
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        // check if the conversion was succeed
        if (row != null)
        {
            // check if the date column is not null
            if (row["ExpiryDate"] != null)
            {
                // try to convert the string into a datetime with a specific format (i am not sure about the date format you are using)
                DateTime dt;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(row["ExpiryDate"], "mm/DD/yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) 
                {
                    // conversion looks ok, do your task                    
                    int compareResult = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, dt);
                    e.Row.BackColor = compareResult == 0 ? System.Drawing.Color.Red : System.Drawing.Color.White; 
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey and thanks, what you write makes sense, I use the MM/DD/YYYY format in the column, though its stored in SQL as Varchar because i couldnt get rid of the timestamp on it when i just wanted the date.

This is probably a stupid question, but i get a

no overload for method takes 4 arguments

when i try your code.

Comment: I edited my awnser. I forgot to add the IFormatProvider parameter. You could pass null anyway, but if you have a spefici culture, would be nice to pass it. Look my edits.

Comment: the best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments.

I get that for the line

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(row["ExpiryDate"], "mm/DD/yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ExpiryDate">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblExpiryDate" runat="server"
                                Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ExpiryDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    ......                       
                </Columns>
```

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string v_ExpiryDate = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ExpiryDate");
            string Test = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,Convert.ToDateTime(v_ExpiryDate)).ToString();
            if (Test == "0")
             {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
             }
           else
             {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
             }
        }

    }
```

Thanks to

Ashim Chatterjee